# c# access .exe and pass parameters to called application without displaying last

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, parameters, exe

Have app1.exe with input parameters and buttons. How to create c# code to access app1.exe pass parameters for input and press button? thanks for any suggestion

Comment: Really don't understand the last part of your question. Press button? which button?

Comment: Voted to close because this question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you can start app1.exe using a process, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx).
2. The only way to 'click a button' in app1.exe is to send a signal/message to the app which has to be handled in app1.exe. Take a look at [this site](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/626029-cross-process-signalling-best-way-doing) for some idea's.